# How to stop a css in header from formatting other objects in html

Tags: html, css

Sorry for asking this basic question as I am new to these languages I am really clueless how to fix this:

Here's the code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
    </head>
  
  <body>
    <!--This is the object that should in't want it to be affected-->
    <div><FORM  method="post">
<table border="2" bgcolor="white" align="RIGHT"cell spacin="1">
<TR><th colspan="2" >Login</th></tr>
<tr><td>Username</td><td> <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="USERNAME" required ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="PASSWORD" maxlength="20" name="PASSWORD"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" ><pre><input type="submit" value="login" NAME="SUBMIT" >             <a href="reg.php">Create Account</a></td></pre>
</div>
</table><div>
</form>
      <!--This is the object should be affected-->
  <form>

  <input  type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">

  </form>
```

The issue I am facing is when i run the code, the table's row username is to big because of the CSS style, I thought of in-lining the CSS command and I did this

```html
<form style="input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}">

  <input  type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">

  </form>
```

Now when I run the code again, I get the search box without CSS been applied, I think I am doing something wrong with the in-lining part - Any pointer or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add greater specificity to your css classes that apply only to the textboxes in your table. Something as simple as this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
/*THE TEXTBOXES INSIDE YOUR TABLE*/
table input[type=text],table input[type=password] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
    </head>
  
  <body>
    <!--This is the object that should in't want it to be affected-->
    <div><FORM  method="post">
<table border="2" bgcolor="white" align="RIGHT"cell spacin="1">
<TR><th colspan="2" >Login</th></tr>
<tr><td>Username</td><td> <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="USERNAME" required ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="PASSWORD" maxlength="20" name="PASSWORD"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" ><pre><input type="submit" value="login" NAME="SUBMIT" >             <a href="reg.php">Create Account</a></td></pre>
</div>
</table><div>
</form>
      <!--This is the object should be affected-->
  <form>

  <input  type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">

  </form>


  
    
 Run code snip
```

Comment: I ran your answer but now the login button row has been formatted, can u just check again and tell me?

Comment: Sorry u were right i just wen through the code again and i found i had copied it wrong soory for that

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, the easiest fix is to use your original code with a minor modification. Instead of using a confusing selector like `input[type=text]`, rather, create either a class or an id and attach it to the input you want styled. In the code below, replaced your original selector with the class `search-input` and applied that class to the form element in question.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
.search-input {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.search-input:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
    </head>
  
  <body>
    <!--This is the object that should in't want it to be affected-->
    <div><FORM  method="post">
<table border="2" bgcolor="white" align="RIGHT"cell spacin="1">
<TR><th colspan="2" >Login</th></tr>
<tr><td>Username</td><td> <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="USERNAME" required ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="PASSWORD" maxlength="20" name="PASSWORD"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" ><pre><input type="submit" value="login" NAME="SUBMIT" >             <a href="reg.php">Create Account</a></td></pre>
</div>
</table><div>
</form>
      <!--This is the object should be affected-->
  <form>

  <input class = "search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">

  </form>
```

Comment: I ran your answer but now the login button row has been formatted same as the above answer yours too has the same problem can u check again

Comment: Sorry u were right i just wen through the code again and i found i had copied it wrong soory for that